# unable to insert into column (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert into my date column of a table where my id column already has a value.I tried to use this query but it gave me error ORA00917 (missing coma)

```
insert into EXAMPLE
(TIME_1)
values(
(TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) 
where ID=23);
```

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: Insert doesn't take a where clause, do you want to update the row where ID = 23?

Answer (score 2):

Insert does not do updates.

```
update example 
set time_1 = TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
where ID = 23;
```